# Scientists make AI machines to save the earth from attacking aliens

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I’m looking for a short story I read a long time ago.. I think it was part of a collection of short stories maybe from the 50’s to 70’s. It goes something like this:

Scientist detect aliens coming to attack earth with still some time until they are here. They try to build machines or AI (not sure if that terminology is used) to protect the earth. The machines are initially not powerful or capable enough to protect against the aliens, but they (the machines) are able to design better machines. This results in exponential development and just in time the aliens can be destroyed and (I think) only 2 of the scientists can be saved. All other humans are lost.

Comment: Can you check if this might be a duplicate of this: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/280208/what-is-this-story-about-an-artificial-intelligence-who-unlocks-infinite-energy/280209#280209 ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff Or this one: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179250/novel-or-short-story-where-a-i-builds-next-gen-a-i

Comment: *Colossus and the Crab*, maybe?

Comment: You can read "The Last Evolution" by John W. Campbell at [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/27462). Is that the one you had in mind? You might have read it in one of [these compilations](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?60642).